# Filter based on named range

Tags: excel

I have a program that automatically generates reports and output them to Excel. The results are stored with names in column A, and corresponding values in columns B->K. I want to use the filter function (or something equivalent) to hide all uninteresting results.

I have a fixed list of names I want to view, but all the names will not be included in the result list every time. Suppose the names in column A are `A, B, C, D, E, F ...` and I want to view `B, D, F ...` I could use `vlookup`. The problem is that sometimes some of the names are missing, for instance it might contain A, B, E, F ..., in which case I would like to see `B` and `F`.

I could use

```
vlookup($A50; $A$2:$K$28; 2; FALSE)
```

where I copied the fixed list to `A50:A64`if all the names existed every time, but this is not the case, thus using the above will return `#N/A` in many cells.

I was hoping I could create a named list, and use it as filtering criterion, but I can't find a way to make this work.

Is there a way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To the person voting to close and voting -1: I would be thankful if you explained why. Why do you think this is off-topic due to lack of "a minimal understanding of the problem"? Please tell me if I failed at any of the points in [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). I have been trying to figure this out for quite a long time, and shared what I have tried (and failed at). If anyone else consider voting down, please add a comment so that I might edit the question. I can't see what is wrong with it as it stands now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Robert:  Are you O.K. with a **VBA** solution??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: I was hoping to avoid it, but after a lot of trying and failing I think it might be the only solution, so **Yes** =) Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `CountIf` in a column and filter on True or False? `=(Countif($A$2:$K$28;$A50)>0)`

Comment: @Sam: Yes, I guess a simple approach would be to use `vlookup` and filter out the rows with `#N/A`. I was hoping it would be possible to do the filtering thing with a named range, but that seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Sort & Filter, Advanced filter seems to provide the required results. Use ColumnA for your List range: and your fixed list of names range as the Criteria range:.

Comment: Is this solution still valid? I am not getting luck on my end.